# How do I fix my code to work out a time difference in days

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix my script that tells my the last time (in days) when a user last logged in.
Currently I get this error

`Fatal error: Unsupported operand types`

My code is as follows:

```
$llogedin= (mysql_query("SELECT `llogin` , `username` FROM `users`"));
```

the below should then show it in table

```
while($t3 =  mysql_fetch_array($llogedin))

    {
echo "               
 <tr>
    <td> ". $t3['username'] ." </td>
    <td> " . $t3['llogin']  - getdate() . " days ago </td>
</tr>";
}
```

I know the error is in the  `<td> " . $3['llogin']  - getdate() . " days ago </td>` but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: 'llogin' is last login - i guess. AND, if you calculate old minus current, you'll get a negative integer, right? Besides, this does not result in "days" anyway.

Comment: I would recommend you to write own `echo` for each line. It is more readable and helps you to understand in which line the error occurs.

Comment: As well, operand types mean you are trying to operate different types. For the minus operator you should use only types that support this operator. Just make sure both sides of the operator `-` are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$example_t3 = ARRAY();
$example_t3[] = ARRAY('username'=>'user_1', 'llogin'=>time()-86401);
$example_t3[] = ARRAY('username'=>'user_2', 'llogin'=>time()-2*86499);
$example_t3[] = ARRAY('username'=>'user_3', 'llogin'=>time()-3*88000);
$example_t3[] = ARRAY('username'=>'user_4', 'llogin'=>time()-4*99999);

echo "<table>";
foreach ($example_t3 AS $t3) {
  $days = intval( (time() - $t3['llogin']) / 86400 );
  echo "
   <tr>
      <td> ". $t3['username'] ." </td>
      <td> " . $days . " days ago </td>
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```